# How to add pagination on a custom Wordpress page that doesn't use wp_query

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a Wordpress custom page that contains e-commerce items. (https://modeseeker.com/baskets-femme/)

I want to use pagination with parameters like ?page=2. I am aware that Wordpress has a pagination system built-in, but I believe I cannot use it as my backend is not wordpress so my items aren't displayed using wp_query.

The problem is that 'page' and 'p' are wordpress reserved terms, so when I try to use an url like https://modeseeker.com/baskets-femme/?page=2, it gets redirected to page 1 without param. I tried to disable redirections using add_filter on redirect_canonical() but then I get an error 404.

```
function page_number_found($redirect_url, $requested_url) {

if (isPageConcatenation($redirect_url, $requested_url)) {
    $redirect_url = $requested_url;
    }
    return $redirect_url;

add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'page_number_found', 10, 2);
```

I expected this to display page 1 and still have ?page=2 in url, but I get an error 404.

So my question is : is there a way to paginate my page using reserved terms but without using a Wordpress query ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This code verifies the existence of the 'page' parameter in the URL and adjusts the 'paged' parameter accordingly. Ensure to incorporate this code into either your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin.

```
function custom_pagination($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
        $query->set('paged', $_GET['page']);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pagination');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. When I go to ?page=2 i still get redirected to main page.

Answer (score 0):

I understood why i get an error 404 when using ?page=2 : it depends on the wordpress permalink structure. If the "post name" structure is used, the url looks like /page/2. If I want to use a structure like ?page=2, I have to revert to a "plain" structure, but it doesn't look good. And there is no option in wordpress to choose an hybrid structure like /baskets-femme/?page=2. So basically no solution.